# How could I fix Error during compodoc run in angular?

Tags: angular, compodoc

enter code here> Blockquote

I have next error during compodoc run in angular (`npx compodoc -p tsconfig.app.json src`)

How can I fix it?

```
Ooops error during main graph generation, moving on next part with main graph disabled : : Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@compodoc/compodoc/node_modules/@aduh95/viz.js/sync/index.js
    require() of ES modules is not supported.
    require() of /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@compodoc/compodoc/node_modules/@aduh95/viz.js/sync/index.js from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@compodoc/compodoc/node_modules/@compodoc/ngd-transformer/dist/engines/dot/dot.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
    Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@compodoc/compodoc/node_modules/@aduh95/viz.js/package.json.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I updated the Node version from 12.16.3 to 14.16.1 and that fixed it.